# Library for getting attributes from html

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for a library, class, function, etc that I can feed it a string of html and find things like src or href.  I know tht I can find a regex for specific cases, but i'm looking for a library that makes it easy to get stuff without figuring out a new regex each time.

Comment: DomDocument php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php will do the trick here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is your friend in this scenario. REGEX is never the best way (for HTML tags).

**Example:**

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
       echo $element->src . '<br>'; # givs you the image 'src' attribute for each image on that page.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working fine for me.  A little extra searching here shows some ppl having problems with it and recommending similar libs.  But so far, so good.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PHP5, it is already natively available to you in the DOMDocument class:

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: This looks good, just not as immediately simple as simpleHTMLDom.  Thanks :)